# rrule weekly for three weeks, then one week not, repeat

Tags: python, python-dateutil, rrule

I'm using [rrule](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-470fa22b2db72000d7abe698a5783a46b0731b57) from python [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) and don't know how to create an rruleset for the following example:

- Monday, three weeks in a row. Then a week not, then again three weeks in a row, one not, and so on.

Any advice on creating an rrule(set) for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use an `rruleset` with a `WEEKLY` rrule and a corresponding exrule for every 4th week:

```
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, rruleset
from dateutil.rrule import WEEKLY

from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

dtstart = datetime(2011, 1, 1)

rrset = rruleset()

weekly_rule = rrule(freq=WEEKLY, dtstart=dtstart)
every_4_weeks = rrule(freq=WEEKLY, interval=4,
                      dtstart=dtstart + relativedelta(weeks=4))

rrset.rrule(weekly_rule)
rrset.exrule(every_4_weeks)

rrset.between(dtstart, dtstart + timedelta(days=65))
```

The result:

```
[datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 8, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 15, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 22, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2011, 2, 5, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2011, 2, 12, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2011, 2, 19, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2011, 3, 5, 0, 0)]
```

The way it works is `weekly_rule` generates one date per week, and the `every_4_weeks` generates every 4th week, starting with the 4th week after `dtstart`. That gives you a 3-on 1-off schedule.

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. I was able to use this as a base for other similiar rrule sets as well.

Comment: @Paul How would this show as an rrule?

Comment: @DeanO I don't understand the question, this is an rruleset, not an rrule.